Replace only the first occurence of two special characters, the rest are removed and no numbers
I need a php preg_replace to allow only the first occurence of ' and -, the rest will be removed and no numbers and other special characters. So Mike O' Hara's Du-Pont Check-In will become Mike O' Haras Du-Pont CheckIn.
I tried this, but it's removing all instances of - and '.
$result = preg_replace("/(')|(-)(?=.*\\1|-)/", '', $string);


preg_replace() has an optional argument that specifies the number of replacements to make. So use this to make it only do the first replacement.

Your title and text say opposite things. The title says replace only the first one, the text says replace all except the first one.

To replace all except the first one, split the string at the first occurrence. Do the replacement in the second part, then concatenate that with the first part.

BTW, you don't need preg_replace() if you're replacing a fixed string. Use str_replace().

thanks @bobblebubble. your first comment works, make it an answer to credit.

Are you going to edit the question to clarify the inconsistency I noted above?

@ruzip Not sure, what exactly you're looking for. Now also remove digits and other special characters? Glad my input helped the way along to your goal. Please try to be as clear as possible, I'm out here.

In one pass, you have to use preg_replace_callback and an array to count the number of occurrences in the callback function:
$str = "Mike O' Hara's Du-Pont Check-In";

$pattern = "~ ' | - ~x";
$cnt = ["'" => 0, '-' => 0];

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use (&$cnt) {
    return $cnt[$m[0]]++ ? '' : $m[0];
}, $str);

In two passes and two patterns designed to return contiguous matches:
echo preg_replace(
    ['~(?:(?!\A)|[^-]*-)[^-]*\K-~A', "~(?:(?!\A)|[^']*')[^']*\K'~A"],
    '',
    $str
);

demo
